# play back video from wowza server to ios device

Tags: ios, streaming, live, wowza

How to play a live stream that is being sent out by a Wowza server,i am using RTMP Streaming and video in .FLV format on server side.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get streaming to an iOS device is by using JW Player together with HTTP Live Streaming (or "Cupertino streaming") from Wowza. However, you say the format is FLV, which iOS doesn't support. If you don't covert it to some other format, your only option is to look for third-party software that plays Flash. Is converting the FLV to another format on the server an option?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using VOD to play an FLV file which is being published (streamed) as RTMP stream. You'll need to use the Wowza transcoder addon which will publish the same stream as HLS/HDS which can be further played on iOS devices. Please see http://www.wowza.com/addons/wowza-transcoder-addon

Also possible to "select" device suitable stream using some other player plugins (such as ipad() for flowplayer).

Thanks and best wishes
Inderjeet S Sodhi
(www.inderjeetsodhi.com)

Answer (score 0):

For connection with wowza you can use RTMP connection and for this

you can implement client side rtmp library

Best RTMP library for iOS available at : https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos

You can use MPMoviePlayerViewController also for doing live streaming.
You have to set MPMovieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming.